# Rule out shaking with calculating g-force in android app

Tags: android, accelerometer

Lots of information out there about how to implement a shake event.  I'm trying *not* to implement one when finding g-force.

I've got a working class with Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER which finds 3-axis g-force, but even so much as jiggling the device registers as > 5G.  I even had the service running while riding my bike and going up the curb to my driveway was a 15G event.

I'm not sure the best way to clean that up or reduce sensitivity of the accelerometer.  Perhaps I could see if that sort of force persisted for greater than X-seconds and then register it as the maximum sustained g-force?

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences, you will most likely have to use a time-based average to make sure it's a prolonged or persistent force instead of a sharp spike.

Mean is typically closer to reality unless you have more shaking than persistent measurements. You can also try a median average, but depending on number of samples from the accelerometer it could be very inaccurate.

Comment: A timed average is along the lines of what I was thinking, so I'm going to have to mess around and see if I can sort something out.

Answer (score 0):

For my purpose a simple low-pass filter combined with a minimum G-Force trigger was all that was needed.

It has been all over StackOverflow, but for posterity:

```
output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
```

Combining that with an appropriate ALPHA setting cleaned up my data enough to work perfectly.